# Error inflating class fragment in Eclipse Android

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to view the map and get an error. 
 I do like in the tutorials, but I still get the same error.

the main class of my application

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

view based on the fragment

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and my manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >



    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBYc19VLUKQTeR6hREcl2REggCO6KPFEk4" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Log from app.

```
10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    ... 11 more

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6111000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.E(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.S(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.R(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.my(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)

10-20 01:58:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(16234):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6111000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the  element: `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Add `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` to your Manifest file within the `<application>` tag.